# Pandas groupby 2 columns to sum and return a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe I am working with and I want to groupby 2 columns, aggregate (sum) another one, and return a new column to the dataframe.

When running the below I can return a whole new dataframe that gets me my results:

```
df.groupby(['Account', 'Year']).agg({'Dollars':'sum'})
```

However I want the return to be in a single column of the original dataframe. I know I could merge this new df with the original as a round-about way of doing this, but I would like to find a single line of code that would complete the task.

For reference, when trying this method I get an error due to 2 variables in the groupby:

```
df['Account_Total'] = df['Dollars'].groupby(['Account', 'Year']).transform('sum')
```

However if I run the above with only 'Account' in the groupby it runs.

The final way I have tried is:

```
df['Account_Total'] = df.groupby(['Account', 'Year']).agg({'Dollars':'sum'})
```

Which clearly does not work as I am trying to add a new dataframe as a column of a dataframe.
(Returns a *TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index*)

Hoping there is an easy solution otherwise I will resort to the merge.

Comment: You are close on the transform.  The error is because you are filtering dataframe only to `Dollars` before the `groupby` and resulting in groupby cannot find the 2 columns.  

Try this `df.groupby(['Account', 'Year']).Dollars.transform(sum)`

Comment: @Emma yup that was it. Thanks!